# Incosistent results when running the same script from different "locations"

Tags: python, command-line, path

I have several functions in several `.py` files, each invoked sequentially from a `main.py` file. All of these files and `main` are in a subfolder `my_subfolder`. I also have the `main.py` file run each night through PythonAnywhere's scheduler. This works just fine.

Today, I wanted to test something new with one of the other files that `main` itself calls each night. The file send emails with an attachment. This attachment is **outside** of the subfolder `my_subfolder`. This is the error I got when I ran the file itself:

```
part = MIMEApplication(open(str("converted_file.docx"), "rb").read())
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'converted_file.docx'
```

So:

1. when calling this `.py` file from `main.py` (both are in `my_subfolder`), everything works fine
2. When running  this `.py` file standalone, it fails to find `converted_file.docx`, which is outside of `my_subfolder`

Note the file itself is 100% there and does not depend on other function calls.

I'm sure there's something I'm missing.

Comment: Um... you're not using the full path of `converted_file.docx` which means that if the .py file trying to read it is not in the same folder, it will not find it.

Comment: Can you post your code so that we can address it?

Comment: @nir0s the `.py` file trying to read `converted_file.docx` isn't in the same folder, but that's the case both when the `.py` is called directly, and through `main.py`, hence my confusion (`main.py` is in the same folder as the other `.py` file).

Comment: Mind posting your code?

Comment: It only matters what directory you're in when you start the python interpreter, where your script files are located is irrelevant. I don't know what this scheduler sets the working directory to before executing a job, probably to the directory containing your docx file. Try to print `os.getcwd()`, that should give you a hint. You can avoid this by using an absolute path to your file.